# Why is Nexus advertising a version, which it wouldn't download?

Tags: maven-3, nexus

A dependency of one of our projects cut a new release four weeks ago -- 1.8.0.

The Nexus metadata duly lists this version as available:

```xml
<metadata modelVersion="1.1.0">
<groupId>com.splunk.logging</groupId>
<artifactId>splunk-library-javalogging</artifactId>
<version>1.7.3</version>
<versioning>
<latest>1.8.0</latest>
<release>1.8.0</release>
<versions>
<version>1.0.1</version>
<version>1.5.0</version>
<version>1.5.1</version>
<version>1.5.2</version>
<version>1.5.3</version>
<version>1.5.4</version>
<version>1.6.0</version>
<version>1.6.1</version>
<version>1.6.2</version>
<version>1.7.0</version>
<version>1.7.1</version>
<version>1.7.2</version>
<version>1.7.3</version>
<version>1.8.0</version>
</versions>
<lastUpdated>20200117004445</lastUpdated>
</versioning>
</metadata>
```

In the project's `pom.xml` file, the dependency's version is set as `<version>[1.7.2,)</version>` and so Maven is trying to download the newly-available 1.8.0. And fails, because our Nexus does not have it for some reason.

Our private Nexus is simply proxying `nexus.pentaho.org` -- which has the same (at the time of this typing) [metadata file](https://nexus.pentaho.org/repository/proxy-public-3rd-party-release/com/splunk/logging/splunk-library-javalogging/maven-metadata.xml) as I copy-pasted above, but not the actual `splunk-library-javalogging-1.8.0.jar` -- though [earlier versions are available](https://nexus.pentaho.org/#browse/search=keyword%3D%22splunk-library-javalogging%22).

Is that, perhaps, because the `<version>` in the above metadata is still set to 1.7.3 -- even though both the `<latest>` and the `<release>` are set to 1.8.0?

Why would that be, and how should I deal with it -- without explicitly excluding 1.8.0?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on the remote web site... the maven-metadata.xml file from that site is showing 1.8.0, but that version isn't available:

https://nexus.pentaho.org/repository/proxy-public-3rd-party-release/com/splunk/logging/splunk-library-javalogging/1.8.0/splunk-library-javalogging-1.8.0.pom

Note that version 1.7.3 is available:

https://nexus.pentaho.org/repository/proxy-public-3rd-party-release/com/splunk/logging/splunk-library-javalogging/1.7.3/splunk-library-javalogging-1.7.3.pom

You'll need to either get the maintainers of that site to fix this, or lock down your version to 1.7.3.

Comment: Ok, but the same question applies to the upstream (Pentaho's) Nexus. Why wouldn't _it_ have the later version? Could it be because the `<latest>` is not the `<version>` for some reason? And what is that reason?